# How to to avoid error message when an empty argument in dplyr::select function?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyselect

This is my code:

```
empty <- ""

mtcars %>% select(mpg,empty)
```

```
Error in `select()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `` doesn't exist.
```

The `empty` object is an output of a for loop. So if empty is equal `""` I wouldn't need to select nothing but I get the error bellow.

In other words, I should be able to select something like this: `mtcars %>% select(mpg,)` . I would need to  transform `""` to

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps using `tidyselect::any_of`

```
library(dplyr)

empty <- ""
vars_select = c(empty, "mpg")

mtcars %>% select(any_of(vars_select))
```

Or create a new variable and set it to `NULL` if it's an empty string:

```
library(dplyr)

empty <- ""

if (empty == "") {
    empty_var = NULL
}

mtcars %>% select(mpg, any_of(empty_var))
```

```
Mazda RX4           21.0
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0
Datsun 710          22.8
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4
Hornet Sportabout   18.7
Valiant             18.1
Duster 360          14.3
Merc 240D           24.4
Merc 230            22.8
Merc 280            19.2
Merc 280C           17.8
Merc 450SE          16.4
Merc 450SL          17.3
Merc 450SLC         15.2
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4
Lincoln Continental 10.4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7
Fiat 128            32.4
Honda Civic         30.4
Toyota Corolla      33.9
Toyota Corona       21.5
Dodge Challenger    15.5
AMC Javelin         15.2
Camaro Z28          13.3
Pontiac Firebird    19.2
Fiat X1-9           27.3
Porsche 914-2       26.0
Lotus Europa        30.4
Ford Pantera L      15.8
Ferrari Dino        19.7
Maserati Bora       15.0
Volvo 142E          21.4
```

Comment: **Extra explanation:** It's likely that `any_of()` is a better fit here because `all_of()` would throw an error if it can't match *ALL* the columns in the vector - which is why you need to replace it with `NULL`. in the second part of the answer.

Comment: @DanAdams whoops yes good point, edited!

Comment: Your original answer was technically correct with `all_of()` - I just thought the clarification would help. E.g. `dplyr::select(mtcars, all_of(c("mpg", NULL)))` doesn't throw an error.